# A claim on Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

I want to understand the following statement on the page 3 of the note written by Martin Hairer: http://www.hairer.org/papers/hormander.pdf on Hormander's theorem.

- Lie bracket $[U, V ]$ is between two vector fields $U$ and $V$ on
  $\mathbb R^n$ is the vector field defined by $$[U, V ](x) = DV (x) U
     (x) - DU (x) V (x).$$ If we denote by $A_U$ the first-order
  differential operator acting on smooth functions  $f$ by $A_U f(x) =
     \langle U(x), \nabla f(x) \rangle$, then we have the identity
  $$A_{[U, V ]} = [A_U, A_V ].$$

My question is how to derive the above claim. I think I am not even clear about the notions here. For instance, what is the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$? If we interpret it by
$$\langle v, u \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i u_i, \forall u, v\in \mathbb R^n,$$
$A_U$ is a mapping from $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R)$ to itself.

Comment: What is $D$ in the first equality? Also, carefull: in order to define Lie bracket, you have to consider smoother things than just $\mathcal{C}^1$, since you differentiate twice.

Comment: $D$ is the gradient. If $U$ is a smooth vector field, $DU$ is a Jacobian matrix.

Comment: As operators, $[A_U, A_V] = A_UA_V - A_VA_U$. So as Didier pointed out, you need to consider at least twice differentiable $f$.

Comment: @Arctic Char, Isn't it $[A_U, A_V] = D A_V A_U - DA_U A_V$ by its definition?

Comment: No according to your definition. $U, V$ are vector fields, while $A_U, A_V$ are linear maps on spaces of functions.

Comment: You need to show that $A_{[U, V ]} f= A_U( A_Vf) - A_V(A_Uf)$ for all smooth functions $f$.

Comment: @ArcticChar it's now clear to me. Thanks for your patience and explanations

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above comments, one wants to show that
$$A_{[U, V]} f = A_U A_V f - A_V A_U f, \ \forall f\in C^\infty.$$
For simplicity, we assume $n = 1$. Then, the left hand side is
$$LHS = [U, V] f' = (UV' - U'V) f',
$$
and right hand side is
$$
RHS = U (V f')' - V (U f')' = (UV' - U'V) f'.
$$